# Why does addEventListener and removeEventListener inside useEffect() require an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect

I'm trying to set onTop state to true if the user has scrolled to the top and false otherwise. I tried the following.

```
function Test()
{
    const [ onTop, setOnTop ] = useState( true )

    const watchScroll = () =>
    {
        if ( window.scrollY < 100 ) setOnTop( true )
        else setOnTop( false )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
        return  window.removeEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
    }, [ watchScroll ])

    return (

        <div>{ onTop ? `On Top` : `Not On top` }</div>

    )
}
```

The above example doesn't work but throws no error either.

```
function Test()
{
    const [ onTop, setOnTop ] = useState( true )

    const watchScroll = () =>
    {
        if ( window.scrollY < 100 ) setOnTop( true )
        else setOnTop( false )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener(`scroll`, () => watchScroll() )
        return  window.removeEventListener(`scroll`, () => watchScroll() )
    }, [ watchScroll ])

    return (

        <div>{ onTop ? `On Top` : `Not On top` }</div>

    )
}
```

Note that I added an arrow and braces to the second parameter function. The above example works as intended. Can anyone explain why? Thanks very much!

Comment: Inline function won't work for removeEventListener btw.

Comment: You can also pass the function reference also. `window.addEventListener("scroll", watchScroll);` Both works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your initial function doesn't work well is because on every re-render a new instance of the function is created and thee previous one is removed since you are passing the function as a dependency to useEffect. Also since you are not executing the `window.removeEventListener` in a cleanup function, it runs immediately causing the listener to be removed immediately.

You can solve it either by

```
function Test()
{
    const [ onTop, setOnTop ] = useState( true )

    const watchScroll = useCallback(() =>
    {
        if ( window.scrollY < 100 ) setOnTop( true )
        else setOnTop( false )
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
        return () => window.removeEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
    }, [ watchScroll ])

    return (

        <div>{ onTop ? `On Top` : `Not On top` }</div>

    )
}
```

or

```
function Test()
{
    const [ onTop, setOnTop ] = useState( true )

   
    useEffect(() => {
        const watchScroll = () => {
           if ( window.scrollY < 100 ) setOnTop( true )
           else setOnTop( false )
       }

        window.addEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
        return ()=> window.removeEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
    }, [ ])

    return (

        <div>{ onTop ? `On Top` : `Not On top` }</div>

    )
}
```

**Also note that with arrow functions**, you solution works because to `removeEventListener` you need to pass the same function reference for it to work properly, if you use arrow function, the listener doesn't cleanup up and hence your implementation works

Comment: Precisely explained. 

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clean up in your effect, you need to return a function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
        return  () => window.removeEventListener(`scroll`, watchScroll )
}, [ watchScroll ])
```